# filter button syntax error during execution

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, winforms, filtering

I have a text box and a filter button to filter the record in my data-grid box , but apparently it is not working and showing error message as

> An Error Occured: Syntax error: Missing operand after "%h%" operator.

And this is my code , please help me how to solve this:

```
Private Sub AlertWarningMessage()
    'Do not allow search while addign record
    MsgBox("The Search Function Is Disabled While Adding New Record",
            MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly Or MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "Find Record")
End Sub

Private Sub SearchButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles SearchButton.Click
    ToolStripStatusLabel1.Text = "Status"
    If IsAddNewRecordInProgress = True Then
        AlertWarningMessage()
        Exit Sub
    End If
    If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(KeywordTextBox.Text) Then
        SearchInAccessDatabase(KeywordTextBox.Text.Replace("'", "''"))
    Else
        RefreshData()
        Return
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub SearchInAccessDatabase(ByVal stringKeyword As String,
                                   Optional stringFilter As String = "")
    Try
        stringFilter = "(Convert(ID, 'System.String') LIKE '" & stringKeyword & "')" &
            " OR ([Size in mg] LIKE '%" & stringKeyword & "%')" &
            " OR ([Die head number] LIKE '%" & stringKeyword & "%')" &
            " OR (Observations '%" & stringKeyword & "%')" &
            " OR (Inspector LIKE '%" & stringKeyword & "%')"
        MSdiesBindingSource.Filter = stringFilter
        If MSdiesBindingSource.Count < 1 Then
            MsgBox("-->>" & stringKeyword & "<<--" & vbNewLine & Environment.NewLine &
                   "The serach item not found", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly Or MsgBoxStyle.Information,
                    "Find Record")
            RefreshData()
        End If


    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("An Error Occured: " & ex.Message.ToString(),
                        "Find Record", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    End Try

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the line

```
OR (Observations '%" & stringKeyword & "%')"
```

you are missing the `LIKE` keyword.

It should be

```
OR (Observations LIKE '%" & stringKeyword & "%')"
```

and because of the optional `stringFilter` parameter, the filter should be set internally only if this parameter has not been passed.

Also, you can simplify the string construction in two ways:

1. You can use string interpolation. For this, introduce the string with a `$`. In the string you can specify expressions to be inserted within curly braces.
2. You can use a multiline string. In VB, this works automatically. If a string is not ended on a line, it is automatically assumed that it continues on the next one.

```
Private Sub SearchInAccessDatabase(ByVal stringKeyword As String,
                                   Optional stringFilter As String = "")
    Try
        If stringFilter = "" Then
            stringFilter = $"(Convert(ID, 'System.String') LIKE '{stringKeyword}')
                OR (Observations LIKE '%{stringKeyword}%')
                OR (Inspector LIKE '%{stringKeyword}%')"
            Dim number As Double
            If Double.TryParse(stringKeyword, number) Then
                stringFilter += $" OR ([Size in mg] = {stringKeyword})
                    OR ([Die head number] = {stringKeyword})"
            End If
        End If
        MSdiesBindingSource.Filter = stringFilter
        If MSdiesBindingSource.Count < 1 Then
            MsgBox($"-->>{stringKeyword}<<--{vbNewLine}{Environment.NewLine}The serach item not found",
                   MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly Or MsgBoxStyle.Information,
                   "Find Record")
            RefreshData()
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show($"An Error Occured: {ex.Message}",
                        "Find Record", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    End Try
End Sub
```

But it depends how you want to filter these two columns. If you want to filter by the start of the number, for instance, then convert the column to a string and go with `LIKE '{stringKeyword}%'`.

The same considerations apply to `ID`. Maybe `ID = {stringKeyword}` is sufficient if the `stringKeyword` is an `Integer` or a `Double` (it depends on the type of `ID`.

Comment: Added the LIKE keyword , now the Error message is :An Error Occurred : Cannon perform 'Like' Operation on System.double and System.String

Comment: Well, `[Size in mg]` is probably a `Double`. What type does `[Die head number]` have? Are there other non string types involved? Either don't include it in the filter if the keyword is not a number or convert the column to a string.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help ....i am very new to this..as you said you are 100% correct that both those fields are double only ...can you please modify the code so that i can filter them too ..